# Gaussian Kernel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

[Torch7 has a library for generating Gaussian Kernels](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/tensorconstruct.md#res-imagegaussiansize-sigma-amplitude-normalize-) over a fixed support. Is there anything comparable in Tensorflow? I see [these distributions in TF contrib](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions/multivariate_distributions#MultivariateNormalDiag), but I am not sure how I would use that to get a kernel (on a fixed grid with weights summing to 1).

Comment: You should be able to create one. For 1D, we have `erf`. For 2D, unless the boundaries are aligned with the covariance matrix, then you might have to do some math. If you only have a finite number of them, I'd suggest you simply construct them unnormalized, then normalize by hand using the empirical sum.

Comment: tf probability has utilities to do this

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following function to generate the kernel to blur images:

```
def gaussian_kernel(size: int, mean: float, std: float):
    """Makes 2D gaussian Kernel for convolution."""
    d = tf.distributions.Normal(mean, std)
    vals = d.prob(tf.range(start = -size, limit = size + 1, dtype = tf.float32))
    gauss_kernel = tf.einsum('i,j->ij', vals, vals)
    gauss_kernel = gauss_kernel/tf.reduce_sum(gauss_kernel)
    return gauss_kernel
```

Kernel size is `2 * size + 1`. E.g. size=2 generates a 5x5 kernel.

I am using it in a lambda layer by convolving the kernel with each channel of the original input (`tf.nn.conv2d`). This is with tf 1.12, but it should for tf2 work with some adjustments (e.g. `tfp.distributions.Normal` instead of `tf.distributions.Normal`)